# Error using DEXSeqDataSetFromHTSeq

Tags: r, bioinformatics, samtools

Currently I am trying to understand `DEXSeq` package. I have a design tsv file and 7 files which contains Counts. Now would like to run the following command

```
library("DEXSeq");

design=read.table("dexseq_design.tsv", header=TRUE, row.names=1);

ecs = DEXSeqDataSetFromHTSeq(countfiles=c("M0.txt", "M1.txt", "M2.txt", "M3.txt", "M4.txt", "M5.txt", "M6.txt", "M7.txt"), design=design, flattenedfile="genome.chr.gff");
```

The last command gives and error

```
Error in class(sampleData) %in% c("data.frame") : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%':
Error: argument "sampleData" is missing, with no default
```

What does this error means and how to fix it? While loading the package `DEXSeq` there was a warning

```
Warning message:
  replacing previous import by ‘ggplot2::Position’ when loading ‘DESeq2’
```

Comment: Your problem is not related to this warning. It just means that both packages `ggplot2` and `DEXSeq` have a `Position` function, and the one from the latter is masking the one from the former.

Comment: so how to fix the error i am facing?

Comment: Without the data, impossible to help further. But according to the error message, `DEXSeqDataSetFromHTSeq` is expecting a `sampleData` you don't have set in your current code.

Comment: M0 to M7 contains all the sample data ..Don't know which sample data its requires .

Comment: `DEXSeqDataSetFromHTSeq` has a `sampleData` argument. Set it. And please read the help page.